# Time distance by roads from specified point (raster analysis)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst

I just started to learn **arcgis**, so even simple tasks looks difficult to me. Can you give me please some guidelines how to create **raster** where each cell contains time distance by road from specified point?

I have following inputs:

- polyline layer with roads (contains table where each road segment has assigned type, so i am able to derive new field with speed limit),
- landuse raster,
- layer with points (cities).

I read something that it can be done by using *network analysis*, but I'm interested in **raster analysis**, since I know some basics about it.

Here is my thoughts:

1. convert roads to raster via "**Polyline to raster**" tool (value field: speed)
2. reclassify roads raster so that, each cell will obtain time derived from speed.
3. ???

Maybe raster analysis contains only distance tools, that computes length as "flight distance". So if network analysis is the only way, what are the steps?

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that I found a solution. The key is to use "**Path distance**" tool, where first parameter, *Input raster or feature source data*, is raster of city and second parameter, *Input cost raster*, is roads raster, where each value has assigned time needed to pass one meter. Roads raster was created in following way:

1. add field "time" to attribute table of roads, where value is
   assigned via "field calculator"
2. "Polyline to raster", where value parameter is "time" attribute.